# The nodes are not changed their positions as the number of ticks in X-axis changed

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to make a scatter plot. I found this problem is confused since as I increase the number of tricks on my X timeline, the node does not change its position! Ideally, the node should be more distributed as the number of tricks increased!

Here is my scale:

```
let xScale = d3.scaleTime()
    //Use d3.extent the minimum and maximum date value
    .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){
        return d.time;
    }))
    .range([margin.left, width - 300])
    .nice(d3.timeDay, 1);
```

and here is I changed the number of ticks on x-axis:

```
    //Build X Axis
    let xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
                  .ticks(d3.timeHour.every(2))
                  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%H:%M'));
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height-margin.bottom})`)
        .call(xAxis)
        .attr("font-size", "15px");
```

Do I miss something in xScale? I guess it is where the problem lies. [image: click here for see difference]

Answer (score 0):

The code works as expected, and the nodes' `x` positions are not supposed to change.

`ticks` are the evenly spaced axis labels. Showing more or less of them does not change the data points.

Let us focus one dot from the question's screenshot.

The event highlighted below happened a bit after 7 am. Whether the ticks are showing intervals of two or four hours, the dot is always correctly positioned.

Two hours tick interval:

[image]

Four hours tick interval:

[image]

The code is correct, nothing to change. Just choose the number of ticks which you feel make the chart most readable wherever it will be displayed.

Comment: Thank you!! It explained well! I just realize this is a stupid question....